# getting sum of sqlite column error

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, textview, android

Why am i getting an error like this? I want to display the sum of my sqlite column Fat on a textview and toast so that I know that it is functioning, But an error show.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
#0x7b
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132)
                      at jm.myapplication.Main.MainActivity.totalFat(MainActivity.java:169)
                      at jm.myapplication.Main.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:498)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This code is on my mainactivity class

```
public void totalFat()
    {
        repo repo = new repo(MainActivity.this);
        int i = repo.totalFatrepo();
        tvtotal.setText(i);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view == findViewById(R.id.water)) {
                totalFat();
            }
            }
```

while this is on my repo

```
public int totalFatrepo(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT SUM(Fat) FROM " + breakfast.TABLE;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int i=c.getInt(0);

        return i;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd look at stack trace you'll see that the problem is not with your database query, but with how you set text to your TextView. If you pass integer to `tvtotal.setText(i)` then it expects a resource id interger (`R.string.some_text` in values.xml).

Call it like below, so that it will trigger another setText method with String as parameter:

```
tvtotal.setText(""+i);
```